# In what structure does Windows keep data about what is the working directory (or the current directory) of the process?

Tags: windows, process, structure, working-directory

While reading on what the working directory and what the script directory (or the directory that contains the image of the executable file) directories are, I started wondering, how does Windows know, what directory to pass to the process as the working directory, when I actually don't specify the working directory when I launch a given program:

[image: working directory-explicit-implicit-Windows]

- Through the command line, I only pass the location of the *script* directory (~as the zeroth parameter). Note that the script directory is *not* the working directory.

I know that I can use [GetCurrentDir()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the working directory inside of the program, but I'm wondering, does Windows have any 'internal' structure that stores the working directory of a given process? (and if yes, is there any documentation on that structure).

I've found out the following process related structures, but it appears none of them contains the working directory property.

- [PROCESS_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [PEB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [PEB_LDR_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell (or the program that launches the script), calls the `CreateProcess()` function. The CreateProcess function has the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter. The shell (or any other program that launches the script), sets the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter *implicitly* (~not through the parameters of the script).

[image: CreateProcess]

That parameter is later stored in the *undocumented* property of the `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structure. [msdnLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [docLink](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.html)

- note the word: *undocumented* (that's why I haven't found the info on msdn in the first place).

[image]

Related stackoverflow questions:

- [Precisely what owns the 'current working directory'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082804/precisely-what-owns-the-current-working-directory)
- [How to set the working directory of a command in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597001/how-to-set-the-working-directory-of-a-command-in-windows-batch-file)
- [Difference between Current Directory and Working Directory in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334097/difference-between-current-directory-and-working-directory-in-windows)
- [How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from/145309#145309)